# Python, remove duplicates from list and convert to one2many

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Being a python newbie I need to solve this pretty simple thing.
Say I have a class:

```
class Event():
  eid = 0
  events = []

  def __repr__(self):
    return "id:"+str(self.eid) + "=>" + str(self.events)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.__repr__()
```

Lets create some instances and save them into a list

```
eventset = list()
e1 = Event()
e1.eid = 0
e1.events = [('1','2','3','A')]

e3 = Event()
e3.eid = 1
e3.events = [('4','5','6','A')]

e2 = Event()
e2.eid = 0
e2.events = [('7','8','9','A')]

e4 = Event()
e4.eid = 1
e4.events = [('10','11','12','A')]

eventset.append(e1,e2,e3,e4)
```

print eventset gives:

```
[id:0=>[('1', '2', '3', 'A')], id:0=>[('7', '8', '9', 'A')], id:1=>[('4', '5', '6',   'A')], id:1=>[('10', '11', '12', 'A')]]
```

I want to create a new list which will look like :

```
[id:0=>[('1', '2', '3', 'A'),('7', '8', '9', 'A')], id:1=>[('4', '5', '6','A'),('10', '11', '12', 'A')]]
```

How to do this elegant a "Pythonic way" ?

EDIT:

1. Need to preserve order of Event elements on the list
2. Do not want to create new Event instance copy

Comment: So you want your class to have 2 separate ways of storing state? You know if you assign a variable to an object, that is a reference to the same object right? so, `a = b` gives `True` for `a is b`. It strikes me that you want the `eid` state to be implicit to an object instance, not part of the api, but I may misunderstand what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should really move the definition of the `eid` and `events` attributes into a `def __init__(self):` method. Doesn't cause a problem in this case, but your `events` list is the same object shared between all instances of the class (until you happen to replace the list by doing `e1.events = []`). Would have acted bizarrely if you used `e1.events.append(...)` or similar

Comment: `def __str__(self): return self.__repr__()` can be written more simply as `__str__ = __repr__`.

Answer (score 2):

What you really need is a dictionary where the key is the `eid` and the items are all your events. I have used [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from collections to give the dictionary a default item - in this case a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in [e1,e2,e3,e4]:
   d[i.eid].append(i.events[0])
```

Comment: Also, I do not see the reason to make a list containing one tuple. @Zdanozdan should perhaps omit the parentheses in e.g. `e1.events = [('1','2','3','A')]`.

Comment: sure, this is just an example, will have more

Comment: Maybe its for having different rooms/attendees for each event, could be useful - but you are probably right its an oversight.

Comment: this is not what I needed :-( new list does not contain instances e1-e4 just eid and events

Comment: So you should have clarified what you wanted in the question? What are you expecting exactly? Do you want to combine your results - that is, take each e1 with the same id and append to the list for e1?

Comment: "take each e1 with the same id and append to the list for e1?" - exactly this is what I wanted

Comment: In your example, `e1` and `e2` have the same `eid`: which one should you add to? `e1` or `e2`? If you want new events combining previous ones, several solutions have been suggested already.

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to "upgrade" `Event` class:

```
class Event(object):  # <-- one change
    eid = 0
    events = []

    def __init__(self, eid=0, events=None): # <-- second change
        self.eid = eid
        if events is not None: self.events = list(events)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "id:"+str(self.eid) + "=>" + str(self.events)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
```

Next:

```
from operator import add, attrgetter
from itertools import starmap, groupby

merge_event = lambda e, events: Event(e, reduce(add, map(attrgetter("events"), events), []))
list(starmap(merge_event, groupby([e1,e2,e3,e4], attrgetter("eid"))))
```

**What's going here**:

`groupby` returns iterator with list of tuples: (`key`, `values`):

```
>>> list(groupby([e1,e2,e3,e4], attrgetter("eid")))
[(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x105d96bd0>), (1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x105d96f10>)]
```

where `key` is your grouping criteria, and `values` is an iterator of matched items. In this code `key` = `eid` attribute (`attrgetter("eid")`) and `values` = all items with the same `eid` value.

`starmap` acts the same as generic `map` but: a) returns iterator instead of list, b) call given callback function with separated arguments (`f(*(key,value)) = f(key, values)`). We created special function `merge_event` to operate with `groupby` output.

`merge_event` takes (`key`, `values`) tuple as arguments and produce one `Event` object. With `key` (which is actually `eid`) everything is clear. To create list of events I use `reduce` function with `add` operator (functional representation from `operator` module). It works in this way:

```
>>> reduce(add, [[1,2,3], ["A","B","C"]], [])
[1, 2, 3, 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

At last, `map(attrgetter("events"), events)` gather for list of `Event` objects only values for `events` attribute (which is list of events).

Comment: +1 for use of itertools, but it may be too much for a beginner to digest. Perhaps you should update it with an explanation of what is going on.

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev that it ! I like it. How to replace [e1,e2,e3,e4] with eventset ?

Comment: @Zdanozdan No, you can just pass `eventset` to `groupby(eventset, attrgetter("eid"))` and that's it.

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev I dont want to produce a new Event instance (merge event lambda) - all instances had been produced already. Just need to append Event.events lists based on Event.eid and then get list (iterator) for instances with unique eid.

Answer (score 0):

@Burkan Khalid's solution is the easiest.

To be fancy, you could transform the output dictionary `d` into another list of events:

```
grouped_events = []
for (i, v) in d:
    e = Event()
    e.eid = i
    e.events = v
    grouped_events.append(e)
```

Of course, that could be simplified if your `Event` class had a proper `__init__` taking a `eid` and `events` as arguments...

```
grouped_events = [Event(i,v) for (i,v) in d.items()]
```

Comment: I was just referring (i) to the lack of `__init__` in the definition of your class (ii) to create **new** `Events` based on the combination of several predefined `Events`.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found pretty nice and quite elegant solution. Please have a look and commet/simplify.

I created an iterator which will return element with eid only if this eid has not been already returned.

```
class first_unique_iter(object):
  def __init__(self, mylist):
    self.eventset = mylist
    self.i = iter(mylist)
    self.used = []

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def next(self):
    element = self.i.next()
    if element.eid not in self.used:
        self.used.append(element.eid)
        return element
    else:
        return self.next()
```

Then comes the logic:

```
def slice_by_id(event, eventset):
   return [e for e in eventset if e.eid == event.eid]

def reduce_2one(x,y):
   x.events.extend(y.events)
   return x

final = [reduce(reduce_2one, slice_by_id(event,eventset)) for event in  first_unique_iter(eventset)]
```

So for every first event with unique eid found we run list comp using this new iterator. Having the list of those for each we need to append list of events from events with same eid. This is done in reduce() function called on sliced by eid list.

```
print final
>>> [id:0=>[('1', '2', '3', 'A'), ('7', '8', '9', 'A')], id:1=>[('4', '5', '6', 'A'), ('10', '11', '12', 'A')]]
```

Could that be simplified any further You think ?